# SignalR at Nopcommerce 4.1 Plugin

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, nopcommerce

I am trying to implement SignalR at Nopcommerce 4.1 Plugin. But getting the below errors.

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:44356/message?id=P70y4-FWNVPuLVFhKTaaKQ' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**

**Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': undefined**

**Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports.**

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports.**

Below is the Hub StartUp. The below methods are calling every startup time.

```
public class AnnouncementHubAtStartUp : INopStartup
{
        public int Order => int.MaxValue;

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
        {
            application.UseFileServer();

            application.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
            });
        }
}
```

Below is my Hub Class

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", message);
        }
}
```

And my contorller is

```
public class LiveAnnouncementController : BaseAdminController
{
    private IHubContext<MessageHub> _messageHubContext;

    public LiveAnnouncementController(IHubContext<MessageHub> messageHubContext)
    {
      _messageHubContext = messageHubContext;
    }

     [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Announcement(AnnouncementModel model)
        {
            AnnouncementDomain objOfAnnouncementDomain = new AnnouncementDomain();
            objOfAnnouncementDomain.Name=model.Name;
            objOfAnnouncementDomain.Body=model.Body;
            objOfAnnouncementDomain.IsActive=model.IsActive;
            objOfAnnouncementDomain.ShowingToDate=model.ShowingToDate;
            objOfAnnouncementDomain.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _announcementService.Insert(objOfAnnouncementDomain);

            if (model.IsActive == true)
            {
                _messageHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("send", model.Body.ToString() +
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

            }

            return RedirectToAction("AnnouncementList");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to decrease the order property of the AnnouncementHubAtStartUp. Because the below extension method

```
   application.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
            });
```

should execute before `NopMvcStartup`.

So the order must be less than 1000. If I change the order 999, Hub connected as expected otherwise not.

The changed code is

```
public class AnnouncementHubAtStartUp : INopStartup
{
    public int Order => 999;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        application.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
        });
    }


}
```

[image]